# How do I point the boot loader to the .efi file indicated by Boot Repair tool

Tags: boot-repair, grub-efi

I ran the Boot Repair tool for Ubuntu and it informed me it corrected my boot issue and reminded me to point the boot loader to sdb1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi.

How do I actually do this?

Comment: Most UEFI just show "ubuntu" as a boot entry. And some like Acer require you to set "trust" on an unknown entry which is the ubuntu entry. You see this in your UEFI boot menu, same key as you used to boot live installer. Once booted or by reviewing the Boot-Repair summary report you can see all the UEFI boot entrys. `sudo efibootmgr -v`  What brand/model system. If you need more help post link to summary report above in your question.

Comment: URL to the summary report from Boot-Repair:https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JRxThcW7zf/

Comment: The ubuntu entry in your UEFI boot menu automatically uses the GUID/partUUID to find ESP - efi system partition. Then a 3 line grub.cfg using configfile loads the full grub.cfg in your install. PartUUID & UUIDs all look like they are using sdb's partitions. See the boot 0001 entry line 32, so that is your boot entry.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look and make sure it is pointed where Boot Repair indicated.